# cannot read para from req.body - unified. Express. JQuery Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

I am trying to pass data in JQuery ajax post to express.

Client side:

```
var returnedValue = [];
returnedValue.push({'key1':value1});
then pass 
{'returnedValue':returnedValue} to the $.post()
```

Serve side app.js

req.body is {returnedValue :[]} .

However, when I try changing the client side code to

JSON.stringify( {'returnedValue':[{'key1':value}]}) to the $.post()

I can successfully get the value at app.js. So I think the body parser is set correctly.

Any idea?

Thanks
Hammer

**more details update**

For {'returnedValue':returnedValue}, I print the req.body on server it shows an empty obj, i.e. {}

Comment: Which version of Expressjs are you using?

Comment: express version is 3.5.0

Comment: After I use JSON.stringify, everything works good now.